# in Kafka sending message from producer with any Partition number still works

Tags: apache-kafka

Why if i set any number as a partition, in the constructor method of the producer, it works and the message is sent even when the partition doesnt exists, does it auto-creates the partition?

Like:

```
await producer.connect();
        await producer.send({
            topic: "my-topic",
            messages: [{ value: JSON.stringify(data) }],
            partition: 200,
        });
```

After that i can consume it normally without errors.

Comment: Which client is this? If KafkaJS, looks like partition should be inside messages block.https://kafka.js.org/docs/producing. Looks more like a syntax issue.

Comment: @Valath  i cant believe i missed that, ive been studying from the same docs. thanks! and sorry if i wasted anyone time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, partition should be inside the message block. thanks @valath